# Using AADL Access Token to Preview Sharepoint Online Document

Tags: access-token, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I'm developing a hybrid mobile application which connects to Sharepoint Online. The authentication has been handled by Cordova AADL which gives an access token after successful login to Azure Active Directory.

I'm able to search SharePoint online document library using Search REST API. Now I want to open/preview the search result document in my app using the access token. Is there any way to do this ? please help

Comment: I don't think there any out of the box preview functionality neither in the Sharepoint Online (SPO) API nor in Cordova. Effectively you'd need to use SPO's file get to download the file and rely on the underlying OS to use whatever file opener they have depending on the file type (probably rely on the user having Office installed).

Comment: @Saca.. yeah may be you are right. We tried different ways and ended up with generating anonymous link for the required document and accessing it from SP.Web.GetObjectSharingSettings